# Alternative Android Image Loading Libraries that can use Uri or String with Japanese Characters?

Tags: android, string, parsing, imageview, picasso

I'm currently doing some preliminary work on seeing if I can get and load data from this Api https://github.com/SchoolIdolTomodachi/SchoolIdolAPI/wiki/API-Songs#get-the-list-of-songs for a capstone Android App.

Right now, I can get the json data, but here comes to issue when it comes to image loading. I want to get the thumbnail for each song so I can place it into a grid of images. I've used Picasso before on a previous project so I attempted that first, unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be able to parse uris or strings with Japanese characters in them.

```
 try {
        String pic2 = "http://i.schoolido.lu/songs/Music_S.T.A.R.T.jpg";
        String pic = new String("http://i.schoolido.lu/songs/これからのSomeday.jpg".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        Picasso.with(this).load(pic).into((ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageview));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {

    }
```

Something like this, the first String pic2 can load an image with Picasso, but the 2nd string pic cannot; there would be no image instead.

Unless I'm totally approaching how to parse Strings with Japanese characters incorrectly, I would like to ask if there are alternative libraries that can load images into an Android App ImageView that can handle Japanese character uris and strings.

Comment: Can you not html encode the characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for everything. I loaded that URL into one of my apps and it handled it without any issues.

```
ImageView coverImg = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Glide.with(YourActivity.this)
                .load("http://i.schoolido.lu/songs/これからのSomeday.jpg")
                .crossFade()
                .into(coverImg);
```

You don't need `.crossFade()` but it'll fade it in nice and pretty for you with that.

Comment: Well, that is one point for Glide. I've actually used Glide before, but it seems my mind processed Picasso usage over Glide. Just tried myself and it worked. Thanks!